# How to open hyperlink in new window under tinymce text editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, text-editor

I have below configuration for tinymce. I want to open the result of hyperlink click in separate tab or window.  I used `theme_advanced_link_targets : "_blank"` as shown below but did not help. Is there any other cofig paramter for this?

```
  var tinyMCESettings = {
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "preview",
    readonly : readOnly,
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
    width : width,
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "false",
    theme_advanced_link_targets : "_blank",
    forced_root_block : false,
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false
  }
```

Answer (score 17):

For TinyMCE 4.0.23 you can use the (undocumented) option:

```
default_link_target:"_blank"
```

as is:

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.rta",
    auto_focus: rta_auto_focus,
    forced_root_block : false,
    statusbar:  false,
    menubar:    false,
    content_css : "content.min.css",
    plugins: [
        "autolink lists link autoresize",
        "searchreplace code",
        "paste"
    ],
    default_link_target:"_blank",
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link"
});
```

Comment: This worked great after upgrading to TinyMCE 4.1.7. However, I'm wondering why it's undocumented and if it's a feature that will remain in future releases. Do you by chance have any information about that?

Comment: A question though  i have is that, isnt the click event of a link inside TinyMCE disabled?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal It is disabled but this allows the the html that is saved to have `target="_blank"` to be included with the markup when you export/save the data from the editor.

Comment: There the documentation link with anchor: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/#default_link_target

Comment: For newer versions is `link_default_target:"_blank"`

Answer (score 9):

Got it resolved with parameter

```
    extended_valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank]"
```

Comment: but you cant turn it off, after you try to edit in the popup-settings and remove "open in new window" you cant turn it off