# TInyMCE Preview Plugin : Link is not clickable

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am uses TinyMCE 4 where I have inserted source content as link

`<a href="http://google.com">Sample Link</a>`

After inserting above content in the TinyMCE, if I click on the preview button of TinyMCE then anchor tag is coming in the form of link but it's not clickable.

Can anyone guide how anchor we can make it as clickable?

> I have followed below links(by adding default_link_target: "_blank"):
>   https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000MrWjAAK
>   &
>   [How to open hyperlink in new window under tinymce text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886712/how-to-open-hyperlink-in-new-window-under-tinymce-text-editor)
>   but none seems to be worked.
>
> but none seems to be worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `preview` plugin has code that specifically stops links from being clickable.  If you look at the JavaScript code for the plugin you will see something like this:

```
var preventClicksOnLinksScript = (
  '<script>' +
    'document.addEventListener && document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {' +
        'for (var elm = e.target; elm; elm = elm.parentNode) {' +
          'if (elm.nodeName === "A") {' +
           'e.preventDefault();' +
          '}' +
        '}' +
    '}, false);' +
  '</script> '
);
```

This code is there specifically to address an issue that could cause a link in `preview` to unintentionally remove the editor instance.

If you click a link in the preview pane that has a `target=_top` you will end up blowing away the editor and replacing it with the content of that link - likely not what you want.

Comment: Hi @Michael Thank you for the reply. I understand that if I alter this part of code to ' preventClicksOnLinksScript  = ""; ' then also link is not clickable. I agree about issue of removing editor instance but my current need is like, I want to enable the click event, so it should redirect to new page. Is there any way around it?

Comment: This seems to be related to : https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000MrWjAAK & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886712/how-to-open-hyperlink-in-new-window-under-tinymce-text-editor but none seems to be worked.

Comment: @AnkitShah if you don't want that code to be part of the `preview` plugin you will need to modify the plugin to remove that code from the rendered content in the preview pane.  Just remember that each time you update TinyMCE you will need to reapply your changes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
>>remove that code from the rendered content in the preview pane<< Where it is? I have tried to remove this whole code above code block from plugin,min.js file of preview plugin and that does not worked.

Comment: @AnkitShah I would modify the non-minified code and then create a new minified version after the edits.  I would test your changes with the non-minified version to make sure it works first and then minify when all done.  If you load TinyMCE itself using a non-minified version it will load all plugins using non-minified code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but maybe it will help someone out there. If you want the links to open in a new window in tinymce prevew plugin remove this script:

`<script>document.addEventListener && document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {for (var elm = e.target; elm; elm = elm.parentNode) {if (elm.nodeName === "A") {e.preventDefault();}}}, false);</script>`

and place this one instead:

`<script>function externalLinks() { for(var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0;a < c.length;a++) { var b = c[a]; b.getAttribute("href") && b.href.hostname !== location.hostname && (b.target = "_blank") } } ; externalLinks();<\/script>`

Enjoy!

Comment: This might be a more helpful answer if you placed your code on [multiple lines with tabs and syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).